# How to change labels on chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

Working with public dataset of house price data. Have a small problem.

Data of property type in terms of D (for detached etc).

Chart looks like this:

[image]

How do I change labels on this chart? Tried clicking labels on marks but option appears to be greyed out.

Answer (score 3):

Best approach is to create calculated field. Name it how you want and assign new names via formula:

**IF [Property type] = 'D' then 'Detached'
ELSEIF ***
END**

Then you can use it instead of [Property type] and edit it whenever you need.

P.S. I suggest to not use aliases, like MKD said.

Comment: I ended up using aliases for time, but like formulas. More resilient.

Answer (score 2):

right click on D, then click on Edit Alias...

Note: this is how i do in window.

Comment: Using Alias is not recommended for something that can be as simple as using the label Mark (using measures etc) this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

"Labels" will appear as "Active" only when you drag a measure from your Data pane to the "Lable" box inside the Marks pane

This is the best practice to apply any lables, dont use Edit Alias without understanding how Tableau works.